# I can't create an outlet in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, uiwebview, iboutlet

I am trying to link a create an IBOutlet for a `UIWebView` Element, however whenever I hold down control and drag from the Storyboard to the `ViewController.h` file, nothing happens and an outlet is not created. I already have an outlet in this file, however, I would like to create another one. Whenever I go to the view controller for the previous outlet and hold control and drag the element to the `ViewController.h` file a new outlet is created. Is there a setting that I have enabled that stops this shortcut from working. Is there another way to create an outlet for ios in Xcode 5.0.1 on Mac OSX 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed issue. The class of the view controller was UIViewController not ViewController. This meant that the ViewController.h and .m files were not showing up under Automatic. Once changed I could view the ViewController.h and .m files and create outlets in them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using storyboard, while it is a lot easier to use, it doesn't let you do many things. To create a new outlet, go to where you want to create it (this will most likely be a `header` file) and then type: `IBOutlet yourOutletType *yourOutletName` so to create a `UIWebView` you would type:

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView
```

and to create an outlet, such as a `UIImageView`, you could type

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView
```

just remember to hook it up in your `.storyboard` file.

Again, I recommend not using storyboard, it *IS* a lot easier, yet it really has lots of limitations

Comment: I am having some trouble linking the IBOutlet Statement to my WebView Element. The control drag shortcut doesn't work. How can I link the UIWebView element in the storyboard to the IBOutlet statement in the ViewController.h file.

Comment: You need not drag it. You can just type it in. Again, I recommend using a `.xib` file, as it is a lot better. You want to put this code in your .h file: `IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView` to define it

Comment: how do I hook the IBOutlet statement to the storyboard

Comment: right click on `yourViewController` on the right. It will be a yellow box, or a white box with a border around it... Again, You should use `.xib` you can do a lot more, and you just have to drag from the `Files Owner` which is always there